# Regex that matches chapter name

Tags: regex

I'm modifying a text e-book that has sequences like this:

```
                           Chapter I
             PREHISTORIC MAN COMES TO NORTH AMERICA
```

with a newline both before and after the mentioned sequence.

I am trying to find a regex that matches the chapter name (in order to remove it)

```
                           Chapter I
                           [nothing]
```

I've come up with:

```
\\n( *)(Chapter(.*?))\\n(.*?)\\n
```

but it seems that it's not recognizing the sequence. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably something in the code, `\n *(Chapter.*\S).*\n.*\n` [works](https://regex101.com/r/QwMuJk/1).

Comment: I combined your answer with positive lookahead&lookbehind in order to find exactly the chapter title in order for it to be replaced.
`(?<=\n *(Chapter.*\S).*\n).*(?=\n)`

Comment: Why do you need lookarounds? Does https://regex101.com/r/QwMuJk/2 work as expected?

Comment: It's working almost as expected but it detects also the Chapter number which I don't want to remove.

Comment: It captures the chapter line and `$1` in the replacement puts it back when replacing. Doesn't replacing `(\n *Chapter.*\n *).*\S` with `$1[nothing]` work ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/QwMuJk/3))?

Comment: I am not sure how I would do that in Python.

Comment: Finally. You need to replace with `\1[nothing]`. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'(\n *Chapter.*\n *).*\S', r'\1[nothing]', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QwMuJk/4).

*Details*:

- `(\n *Chapter.*\n *)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this text from the replacement pattern): a newline, zero or more spaces, `Chapter`, then zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, a newline and then zero or more spaces
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\S` - a non-whitespace char.

Comment: It does indeed work, and as regex101 warned me it's probably faster that the way with lookarounds.